# Comparator comparing type inference

Tags: java

Let's say change `Comparator.comparing` source code from

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
    Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)
{
  Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
  return (Comparator<T> & Serializable) (c1, c2) -> keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
}
```

to

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
    Function<T, U> keyExtractor)
{
  Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
  return (Comparator<T> & Serializable) (c1, c2) -> keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
}
```

And we have the follwing classes

```
class PhysicalObject {
  double weight;
  public Double getWeight(){
    return weight;  
  }
}
class Car extends PhysicalObject {}
```

The following statament does not compile

`Function<PhysicalObject, Double> weight = p->p.getWeight();`

`Comparator<Car> c = HypotheticComparators.comparing(weight);`

while this compile `Comparator<Car> c3_1 = HypotheticComparators.comparing(PhysicalObject::getWeight);`

I understand that the first statement can't compile is because the modified comparing function does not have the bounded wildcard (`? super T`), but why the second statement can compile without any problem ?

Comment: Something went wrong with the **c**lass declarations and p**hysica**l objects, consider verifying the code snippets in your question with an actual java compiler.

Comment: Because you can't pass a Car to a Function<PhysicalObject, Double>, but the compiler can use type inference to type the method reference PhysicalObject::getWeight as a Function<Car, Double>.

Answer (score 1):

With `comparing` defined as:

```
Comparator<T> comparing(Function<T, U> keyExtractor) // abbreviated
```

the statement:

```
Comparator<Car> c = comparing(weight);
```

requires argument to be a `Function<Car, ?>`, but `weight` is a `Function<PhysicalObject, Double>` so you get the compile error.

However, when doing

```
Comparator<Car> c3_1 = comparing(PhysicalObject::getWeight);
```

the `Function<Car, ?>` method `? apply(Car t)` is adequately implemented by the `Double getWeight()` of superclass `PhysicalObject`, since `t->getWeight()` is a call to that method.

The `PhysicalObject::getWeight` method reference is like the following lambda:

```
Comparator<Car> c3_1 = comparing((Car t) -> {
    PhysicalObject p = t;
    return p.getWeight(); // call PhysicalObject::getWeight
});
```

Or the following anonymous class:

```
Comparator<Car> c3_1 = comparing(new Function<Car, Double>() {
    @Override
    public Double apply(Car t) {
        PhysicalObject p = t;
        return p.getWeight();
    }
});
```

The widening conversion from `Car` to `PhysicalObject` is allowed in a method reference.

Answer (score 0):

According to the JLS ([§18.2.1: Expression Compatibility Constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/jls9.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A8622%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C72%2C207%2Cnull%5D)), this is due to the Reduction stage for exact method references within the chapter on Type Inference, as seen by the image below.

[image]

Essentially, the compiler is able to infer that, because `Car` extends `PhysicalObject`, it should be able to define a `Comparator<Car>` with a `Function<Car, Double>`.

Explicitly passing a `Function<PhysicalObject, Double>` to create a `Comparator<Car>` will not work though, as there is not enough information available for the compiler to properly infer it.

Comment: @Andreas I did, my bad!